# A single word for “one who boasts about knowing or dating famous people”

Tags: single-word-requests

If I am not wrong, I once encountered a British word used (in slang I suppose) to describe a person who boasts about going out, knowing or dating famous people. Does it exist? In this case, is it common?

Comment: Does the person *actually* know the famous person? Or are they just making it up? If they're making it up it might come under the generic term "BSer". (B and S are normally replaced with other words, but I'm typing this at work...)

Comment: While not the strict definition of, that is one of more common traits attributed to a *poser*, who uses popular references to bolster their 'cred'.

Comment: there is a vulgar term for this, "Star-f*****"   Essentially, it is an exact simile for "name-dropper".

Comment: @Fattie I very much disagree. Starfucker literally means what it says—a person who has sexual relations with famous people. A name-dropper is simply a person who knows (or pretends to know) famous people, and frequently mentions the fact that they know them.

Comment: @ell I totally know what you mean.  In fact I was going to comment:  *"Strangely, people seem to use starf'er to mean name-dropper, even though you'd think the word would specifically mean more like a groupie."  All I can say is in my experience, folks do use it as a synonym for "name-dropper".

Comment: Which is it, knowing (or having met) vs dating? Those are pretty different things socially and will likely have different words (if any).

Comment: @Mitch I don't mean "knowing" in the biblical sense, and I don't expect most would interpret it that way.

Comment: @ell Neither did I. 'vs' means you're putting two things in contrast and 'dating' is more likely to involve sex. 'name-dropping' vs 'star-f***ing'.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Are you thinking of [name-dropping](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/name-dropping) (MW)?

> the studied but seemingly casual mention of prominent persons as associates done to impress others

Name-dropping is the verb form, the noun is name-dropper.

Comment: Yeah that's the one. I know that for a fact because I just called up Stephen Fry and he said "yeah that's the one".

Comment: Only now I understand that my question was not precise, it was a verb not an adjective, thank you!

Comment: @RegDwigнt **clang**

Comment: FYI @christo, as an American, this would be the proper word to use as well. Just clarifying it is not strictly British.

Comment: If you want to emphasize the _why_   (attempting to impress others) more than the _how_ (name dropping), you could always go with poseur

Comment: @MichaelJ. That could be an answer on its own :)

Comment: @RegDwigнt - pretty funny, for someone with your user name... :-)

Comment: As I mention above, "Starf***er" is a vulgarity which is, basically, an exact simile for this.  And yes as others have said "name-dropper" is not at all British.  (Actually, I'd guess it is US origin.)

Answer (score 9):

If your use of "knowing" is the biblical sense of the word, there is also the term "starfucker".

Comment: isn't that just a "groupie"?

Comment: This answer is extremely confusing.  "Starfucker" is a totally normal, commonplace, slang.

Comment: I actually edited the answer for clarity.  (obviously - as always - anyone else can edit it back again.)

Comment: I don't know the policy on using swear words in answers.  I don't appreciate being dressed down for being cautious and respectful to the reader's sensibilities.

Comment: The policy on swear words is: observe the use versus mention distinction. Don't *use* swear words, but feel free to *mention* them. In other words, if you intend your answer to be *starfucker*, you are most welcome to write *starfucker*.

Answer (score 1):

The Term "[Groupie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groupie)" is often used in this case.

While, most commonly used in reference to a band/musical artist, it can also be used in context with any famous person or group.

Comment: Are groupies defined by boasting about it, or by doing it?

Comment: @AntonSherwood - Point taking Groupie for those that have done it and wannabe for those that havent?